# Magento 2, extending sales module's Model, getting error Required type: \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface

Tags: magento2, sales-order, override-model

I'm trying to override `\Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create`, during the compilation I'm getting below, but I'm not making any changes, simply extending it!

```
Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface. Actual type: array; File:
/app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php
```

and here is my file:

```
<?php


// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Model\AdminOrder;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form as CustomerForm;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

/**
 * Order create model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Create extends \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create
{
    /**
     * Xml default email domain path
     */
    const XML_PATH_DEFAULT_EMAIL_DOMAIN = 'customer/create_account/email_domain';

    /**
     * Quote session object
     *
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote
     */
    protected $_session;

    /**
     * Quote customer wishlist model object
     *
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist
     */
    protected $_wishlist;

    /**
     * Sales Quote instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    protected $_cart;

    /**
     * Catalog Compare List instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\ListCompare
     */
    protected $_compareList;

    /**
     * Re-collect quote flag
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $_needCollect;

    /**
     * Re-collect cart flag
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $_needCollectCart = false;

    /**
     * Collect (import) data and validate it flag
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $_isValidate = false;

    /**
     * Array of validate errors
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_errors = [];

    /**
     * Quote associated with the model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    protected $_quote;

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * Core event manager proxy
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_eventManager = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Config
     */
    protected $_salesConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy
     */
    protected $_objectCopyService;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Product\Quote\Initializer
     */
    protected $quoteInitializer;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $addressRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $addressFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory
     */
    protected $_metadataFormFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $groupRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
     */
    protected $stockRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\EmailSender
     */
    protected $emailSender;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Updater
     */
    protected $quoteItemUpdater;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Factory
     */
    protected $objectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $accountManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Mapper
     */
    protected $customerMapper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface
     */
    protected $quoteManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper
     */
    protected $dataObjectHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface
     */
    protected $orderManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
     */
    protected $quoteFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Config $salesConfig
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $quoteSession
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy $objectCopyService
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Product\Quote\Initializer $quoteInitializer
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory $addressFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $metadataFormFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param EmailSender $emailSender
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
     * @param Item\Updater $quoteItemUpdater
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Factory $objectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Mapper $customerMapper
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $quoteManagement
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Config $salesConfig,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $quoteSession,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy $objectCopyService,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Product\Quote\Initializer $quoteInitializer,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory $addressFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $metadataFormFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\EmailSender $emailSender,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Updater $quoteItemUpdater,
        \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Factory $objectFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Mapper $customerMapper,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $quoteManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_salesConfig = $salesConfig;
        $this->_session = $quoteSession;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_objectCopyService = $objectCopyService;
        $this->quoteInitializer = $quoteInitializer;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;
        $this->_metadataFormFactory = $metadataFormFactory;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->emailSender = $emailSender;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        $this->quoteItemUpdater = $quoteItemUpdater;
        $this->objectFactory = $objectFactory;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
        $this->customerMapper = $customerMapper;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        parent::__construct($data);
    }
    /**
     * 
     *
     * Here I may write my logic
     */


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is complete working code you can use 
app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyVendor_MyModule" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
</config>
```

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Magento\Sales\AdminOrder\Create" />

</config>
```

MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Magento\Sales\AdminOrder\Create.php

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Magento\Sales\AdminOrder;
class Create extends \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create
{

}
```

Hope it Helps !!